# ngb-datepicker does not update model value when using custom NgbDateParserFormatter

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngb-datepicker

I created a custom component that holds inside an angular date picker, problem is that I need to format the way the date is displayed depeding on the app's selected language, that why I created a custom NgbDateParserFormatter. When I provide my custom formatter the date is displayed correctly, but the model value is not updated when I try to get the value from a parent component, it just works when I remove my custom provider, but I far  as I understand the formatter shouldn't affect that.

Here is my custom date picker component

custom-datepicker.html

```
<div>
  <input
    ngbDatepicker
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="date"
    #dateInput="ngbDatepicker"
    (click)="onToggle(dateInput)"
    (ngModelChange)="onChangeDate($event)"
    ngControl="date" name="dateInput"/>
  <button class="btn input-group-text date-picker-toggle-btn" (click)="dateInput.toggle()" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

custom-datepicker.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NgbCalendar,
  NgbDateStruct,
  NgbDatepickerI18n,
} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [],
})
export class DatePickerComponent {
  @Input('date')
  date: NgbDateStruct;
  @Output()
  dateChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  today = this.calendar.getToday();

  constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) {
  }

  onChangeDate(newDate: any) {
    this.dateChange.emit(newDate);
  }

  onToggle(dateInput) {
    dateInput.toggle();
  }
}
```

ngbDateCustomParserFormatter.ts

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

function toInteger(value: any): number {
  return parseInt(`${value}`, 10);
}

function isNumber(value: any): value is number {
  return !isNaN(toInteger(value));
}

@Injectable()
export class NgbDateCustomParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe, private translator: TranslateService) {
    super();
  }

  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
    if (value) {
      const dateParts = value.trim().split('-');
      if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
        return {day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null, year: null};
      } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
        return {day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]), year: null};
      } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1]) && isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
        return {day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]), year: toInteger(dateParts[2])};
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    let dateObj = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
    return this.datePipe.transform(dateObj, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  }
}
```

And this is how my componen is being used in the paren component html (expirationDate id a `NgbDateStruct`)

```
<date-picker [(date)]="expirationDate" id="expiration-date" />
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify. I have added the provider in the AppModule and the custom date picker component, it's when I add it to the providers when the model doesn't get updated, when I remove that provider the model gets updated correctly.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateCustomParserFormatter}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyones expiriences the same problem, check your parser, forgot to change the parser so it was trying to parse DD/MM/YYYY dates and the parser was expecting YYYY-MM-DD dates

Answer (score 0):

See that it's necessary add in provider the adapter. In your DatePickerComponent.ts (you can also add in your app.module.ts)

```
providers: [
        { provide: NgbDateParserFormatter , useClass: NgbDateCustomParserFormatter},
        
        //If you want also to use a CustomDate adapter
        { provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateCustomDateAdapter } 
    ],
```

Comment: I have added the provider in the AppModule and the custom date picker component, it's when I add it to the providers when the model doesn't get updated, when I remove that provider the model gets updated correctly